# Error "Disallowed system call: SYS_kill" as I try to remove all consecutive duplicate elements from a string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

The following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void remove_duplicates ( std::string & s )
{

   for (std::string::iterator it(s.begin()), offend(s.end()); it != offend; ++it)
   {
      std::string::iterator temp = it;
      while (++it != offend && *it == *temp);
      if ((it-temp)>1) s.erase(temp, it);
   }
}


int main()
{
   std::string str = "aaabbcaaaaa";
   remove_duplicates(str);
   std::cout << str; /* Expected output: "abca" */
   return 0;
}
```

is producing the error

> /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/basic_string.h:1154:
>   __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator::other::pointer, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> > std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::erase(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator::other::pointer, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator::other::pointer, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> >) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits, _Alloc = std::allocator]: Assertion
>   '__first >= _M_ibegin() && __first <= __last && __last <= _M_iend()'
>   failed.
>
> Disallowed system call: SYS_kill

when I run it on http://codepad.org/KXgHqKS2.

Is there a problem with the logic of my function? If so, what is it, and is there a cleaner way to solve the problem?

Comment: Aren't you invalidating your iterators inside that loop? Good luck in the election.

Comment: You should read the error message more carefully: "Assertion [...] failed.". In other words, something happened that represents a programming error, either in your code or, very unlikely, in the implementation of the C++ standardlibrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a problem with the logic of my function?

Yes, erasing elements invalidates the iterators. If you want to do this by steam, you'll need to make two changes:

- don't store the `end` iterator between iterations, or update it after erasing;
- update `it` after erasing, `it = erase(temp, it)`

> Is there a cleaner way to solve the problem?

```
s.erase(std::unique(s.begin(), s.end()), s.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

The code `s.erase(temp, it);` invalidates the iterator `it`, and `++it` in the `for` loop then becomes undefined behavior.

Following is my implementation of `remove_duplicates` for your interest:

```
void remove_duplicates(std::string& str) {
  if (str.empty()) return;
  std::string::iterator it = str.begin();
  std::string::iterator itt = it + 1;
  while (itt < str.end()) {
    if (*itt == *it) {
      ++itt;
    }
    else {
      *++it = *itt++;
    }
  }
  str.resize(it - str.begin() + 1);
}
```